# How to generate random characters

Tags: android, random

I am new to the android developement. I been reading tutorials , learning and testing.

I am making my own personal app , and I need to know how to generate a string of letters and letters between A-Z and 0-9.

If somebody could help this would be apreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    final TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
    100));
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("push");
    txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
    100));
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] chars = {"a","b","c","d","e","x","y","z","0","1","2","8","9","10"};
            txt.setText(chars[(int) (Math.random() * 10)]); 
        }
    }); 

    linear.addView(txt);
    linear.addView(btn);
    setContentView(linear);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Something like this perhaps:

```
import java.util.Random;
Random rnd = new Random();
int numLetters = 10;

String randomLetters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int n=0; n<numLetters; n++)
  Log.i("Random letters" randomLetters.charAt(rnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));
```

Comment: Yes Exacly. But how can I use this with one button ? Then when the button is clicked it generates the letters and numbers into a plain text box ? thanks